Stack Smashing Detected in C Program – Aborted (Core Dumped) Issue
I'm new to C and tried the following experiment while learning. However, I couldn't fully understand the behavior of the program. Could someone please explain it to me?
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main() {
    int number[5];
    printf("SIZE of number = %u\n", sizeof(number));
    for(int i = 0; i<10; i++){

        // if(i >5){
        //     printf("BYE.. braking the loop");
        //     return 0;
        // }
        printf("\n %d ::",i);
        number[i] = i;
        printf("Added");  
    }
  return 0;
}

Here the output when I execute the code ::
SIZE of number = 20
0 ::Added
1 ::Added
2 ::Added
3 ::Added
4 ::Added
5 ::Added
6 ::Added
7 ::Added
8 ::Added
*** stack smashing detected ***: terminated
Aborted (core dumped)
know this program will crash due to accessing memory out of bounds, but I expected it to crash when i = 5. However, it doesn't crash at that point and instead continues until i = 8. Additionally, I observed another behavior that I will mention below.
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main() {
    int number[5];
    printf("SIZE of number = %u\n", sizeof(number));
    for(int i = 0; i<10; i++){

        if(i >5){
            printf("BYE.. braking the loop");
            return 0;
        }
        printf("\n %d ::",i);
        number[i] = i;
        printf("Added");
       
    }
  return 0;
}

For the above code  output is:
SIZE of number = 20
0 ::Added
1 ::Added
2 ::Added
3 ::Added
4 ::Added
*** stack smashing detected ***: terminated
Aborted (core dumped)
Could someone help me understand why this is happening?

Going out of bounds of an array leads to undefined behavior. When, or even if it crashes depends on many different factors. Just make sure it doesn't happen.

Yes, it's because of the array out of boundary, first code, it's add till 8  and i uncommand the if statement it crashes at expected position , but it's not happening in the first condition @Someprogrammerdude.

"I expected it to crash when i = 5" - Accessing an array out of bounds has undefined behavior. It may crash, but may do something completely different. It's undefined so you should expect anything from it.

@TedLyngmo can you explain it  , still not figure out what is going on , and undefined mean?

My Doubt is: why does the program crash in the second case when i = 5, but not in the first case? What causes the different behavior between the two cases?

That is the way of undefined behavior. You can't really tell when, where and why things happen. It might even summon nasal demons or set your pet on fire (well, unlikely, but UB is so broad that once you have it then there's really nothing to be explained).

@sathishk Undefined means that the C standard does not define what will happen when you do this. It does not say that the program should crash. It does not say that the program should print Hello - yet both are possible
